# Set USB device bitrate and bandwidth on Android (Bibliography)

Tags: android, usb, libusb

I am trying to set an audio USB device from my app in Android using libusb (https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/android). I get the permission to give access to the device, but I don't know how to query the bitrates and bandwidths supported by the device and set one.

I couldn't find much information about handling USB devices at a low level, so does some bibliography exist?

Answer (score 0):

I found a book called Unboxing Android USB that is quite usefull. 
I recommend it to everyone.